# Insert trigger checking for specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an insert trigger on a table. The table has a column `source`.

The `source` column could be populated with values b or left empty as in null.

I want the trigger only to fire if the `source` column is not populated with 'b'. The below trigger codes doesn't give me error, it just never runs.

If I remove the `if` condition it runs, but I need to check for value of 'b' before it should run.

```
Create TRIGGER TriggerName
ON tableName
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @source nvarchar(50)

    SELECT                  
        @source = (select source  from inserted)

    if not (@source = 'b') 
    begin
        INSERT INTO ATable(field1, field2, field3)  
           SELECT 
              i.field1, i.field2, i.field3
           FROM 
              inserted i 
    end
end
```

Comment: [Please don't cross-post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76113/sql-server-insert-trigger-checking-for-specific-column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger will not handle multiple row operations. You should NOT be using a scalar value inside a trigger. Your entire trigger should be rewritten like this.

```
INSERT INTO ATable
(
    field1
    , field2
    , field3
)  
SELECT i.field1
    , i.field2
    , i.field3
FROM inserted i 
WHERE i.source = 'b'
```